# vue 2 @click handler not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a "card" component with many "faces".
Click the card and it shows another face.

```
<template lang="pug">
  .infini-card(@click.prevent="clickCard")
    infini-card-empty(v-if="face==='empty'")
    infini-card-secret(v-if="face==='secret'" v-bind="cardData")
    infini-card-reveal(v-if="face==='reveal'" v-bind="cardData")
</template>
```

The ".infini-card" div has a click handler and I can do a switch() there to process changes for all the different kinds of faces.  Cool.

But, the first thing I tried didn't work:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .infini-card
    infini-card-empty(v-if="face==='empty'")
    infini-card-secret(v-if="face==='secret'" v-bind="cardData" @click.prevent="clickSecret")
    infini-card-reveal(v-if="face==='reveal'" v-bind="cardData")
</template>
```

The clickSecret() method is never called on the v-if'd face.  This component is instantiated in another pug template like this: `infini-card(v-bind.sync="cardA")`

Why?  :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `@click` works differently for native elements vs vue components.

On a native component (`<div>, <button>`), `@click` listens for the a click event.

On a custom component (`<infini-card-secret>`), `@click` listens for a event emit 'click' from that custom component (`this.$emit('click')`)

- To make sure `@click` listens for the native click event on custom components, use the `.native` modifier, like this:
- `@click.native="clickSecret"`.

Vue Docs: [Binding Native Events to Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components)